# mySQL, need help getting many sub-queries into 1 SELECT query (displays 13 columns)

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1242

this is my first post. I know that this is horribly inefficient and repetitive code that won't actually work, what I need to do is combine all these outputs into 1 select statement. I am obviously fairly new at this, but I've been at it all day and I just can't get started in the right direction, each snippet works on its own...please help!

Essentially I'm working with a DB with many tables, and to get the right data for each column, I often have to account for 3 tables with joins.

Thanks for any insight or help!

```
SELECT 
  Product.ProductID,
  (
  SELECT Abbreviation AS Country
  FROM Product
  LEFT JOIN ProductCountry 
    ON Product.ProductID = ProductCountry.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN Location 
    ON ProductCountry.LocationID = Location.LocationID
  GROUP BY Product.ProductID
  ),

  (
  SELECT r.ResourceName AS Manufacturer, rr.ResourceName AS Brand
  FROM Product p
  LEFT JOIN Resource r 
    ON p.ManufactureCode = r.ResourceID
  INNER JOIN Resource rr 
    ON p.BrandCode = rr.ResourceID
  ),

  Product.Name,
  Product.UPC,
  Product.Size,

  (
  SELECT Unit.abbreviation AS Measure
  FROM Product
  LEFT JOIN Unit 
    ON Product.Unit = Unit.UnitID
  ),

  (
  SELECT Category.ParentID AS Category, Category.Description AS Sub_Category
  FROM Product
  LEFT JOIN ProductCategory 
    ON Product.ProductID = ProductCategory.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN Category 
    ON ProductCategory.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
  ),

  (
  SELECT i.Description AS INGREDIENTS, i.MayContain AS Allergen_Statement
  FROM Product
  LEFT JOIN Ingredient i 
    ON Product.ProductID = i.IngredientID
  ),

  (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Special.Description SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS Free_From
  FROM Product
  LEFT JOIN ProductSpecial 
    ON Product.ProductID = ProductSpecial.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN Special 
    ON ProductSpecial.SpecialID = Special.SpecialID
  GROUP BY Product.ProductID
  )

FROM Product, ProductStatus
WHERE ProductStatus.ProductStatusID = 1
```

Comment: Some of the subqueries use mysql Kung Fu (the magic group-by) that can't be brought out so easily. I think you should start from scratch. Take a snapshot of the output and keep working on the new version until its output is the same.

Comment: @Bohemian If the ultimate goal is to export these 13 columns into excel, would I be best using php to manipulate the output?

Comment: I would avoid introducing another layer. Get the query right. Also, if the query works, and you're only exporting to excel, why do you care about performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some notes and assumptions...

- I'm assuming the `Country` column is in the `Location` table, otherwise why would you bother joining it.
- If you have trouble with this part, change the second join to a `LEFT JOIN`. I've had occasional trouble doing `left join a to b` followed by `inner join b to c`. I've found it's easier to keep the `LEFT JOIN` going, so my example left-joins both tables:

  ```
    LEFT JOIN Resource r 
      ON p.ManufactureCode = r.ResourceID
    INNER JOIN Resource rr 
      ON p.BrandCode = rr.ResourceID
  ```
- You're joining to `Resource` in two different ways. That's completely OK with MySQL (and all the mainstream databases). You just have to alias one or both of the joins. I've aliased one of them:

  ```
  LEFT JOIN Resource ON Product.ManufactureCode ...
  LEFT JOIN Resource BrandResource ON Product.BrandCode...
  ```
- I don't know from your example how `ProductStatus` is joined. You'll have to supply that.
- Start small using the example below. Join in the `Country`, then when you've got that working, join in `Manufacturer`, then `Brand`, then `Measure`, etc. The query isn't doing a lot of advanced stuff; it's complicated mostly due to the sheer number of tables. Tackle them one at a time and you'll win :)
- Finally, as @Bohemian noted in the comments, the `GROUP BY` can't be brought up to the top. Actually, it probably can, but it will complicate things beyond belief. I've left that as a subquery.

Here's the final result. Note that it's not tested because it's huge and I don't have table structures or sample data. But mostly because it's huge :) At any rate, this is meant as an example only.

```
SELECT 
  Product.ProductID,
  Location.Country,
  Resource.ResourceName AS Manufacturer,
  BrandResource.ResourceName AS Brand,
  Product.Name,
  Product.UPC,
  Product.Size,
  Unit.Abbreviation AS Measure,
  Category.ParentID AS Category,
  Category.Description AS Sub_Category,
  Ingredient.Description AS Ingredients,
  Ingredient.MayContain AS Allergen_Statement,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Special.Description SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS Free_From
    FROM Product
    LEFT JOIN ProductSpecial 
      ON Product.ProductID = ProductSpecial.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN Special 
      ON ProductSpecial.SpecialID = Special.SpecialID
    GROUP BY Product.ProductID
    )
FROM Product
  INNER JOIN ProductStatus ON ... however it's joined
  LEFT JOIN ProductCountry ON Product.ProductID = ProductCountry.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN Location ON ProductCountry.LocationID = Location.LocationID
  LEFT JOIN Resource ON Product.ManufactureCode = Resource.ResourceID
  LEFT JOIN Resource BrandResource ON Product.BrandCode = BrandResource.ResourceID
  LEFT JOIN Unit ON Product.Unit = Unit.UnitID
  LEFT JOIN ProductCategory ON Product.ProductID = ProductCategory.ProductID
  LEFT JOIN Category ON ProductCategory.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
  LEFT JOIN Ingredient ON Product.ProductID = i.IngredientID
WHERE ProductStatus.ProductStatusID = 1
```

Comment: You are amazing! I played with it a little more and presto it's returning everything properly!